# Can you extract information from a C executable about which source files it was compiled from?

Tags: c, executable

I have a C executable and would like to know if the executable has any information stored in it about which file(s) it was compiled from and, if so, how to access that information?  I am using RedHat Linux 6.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I'd use ``strings`` and ``ldd`` and a bit of guesswork meself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program has been compiled with debugging information, then yes, it's possible.

For example, I compiled `test.c` with `gcc -ggdb3 test.c -o test`

Then, with `gdb ./test`:

```
(gdb) info functions
All defined functions:

File main.c:
int main(int, char **);

Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000400370  _init
0x00000000004003a0  __libc_start_main@plt
0x00000000004003b0  __gmon_start__@plt
0x00000000004003c0  _start
0x00000000004003f0  deregister_tm_clones
0x0000000000400420  register_tm_clones
0x0000000000400460  __do_global_dtors_aux
0x0000000000400480  frame_dummy
0x00000000004004d0  __libc_csu_init
0x0000000000400540  __libc_csu_fini
0x0000000000400544  _fini

(gdb) info sources
Source files for which symbols have been read in:

/home/john/Projects/test/main.c, /usr/include/bits/sys_errlist.h, ...

Source files for which symbols will be read in on demand:
```

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on the architecture, and whether the executable was compiled in debug mode (or similar).

For example, UNIX systems embed debug information (including file names) in the executable itself, whereas Windows stores the info in a separate file (i.e. `myprog.exe` has a corresponding `myprog.pdb` with all the debug info).

Comment: In that case, it probably doesn't have any of the source filenames in it.